# Problema con consulta SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quiero hacer lo siguiente:

Devolver el importe total de depósitos del año, el importe total de retiros del año y el promedio de importes movidos también en el año

Esta es mi consulta:

```
Select TablaDeposito.Deposito,
TablaRetiro.Retiro,
AVG(TablaTransferencia.Trans) as Transferencia    
from (
        SELECT Sum(m.ImporteMovim) as Deposito 
        FROM Movimiento M
        where m.TipoMovim='E' and YEAR(M.FchMovim)=2019
    ) TablaDeposito ,
    (
        SELECT sum(m.ImporteMovim) as Retiro 
        FROM Movimiento M
        where m.TipoMovim='S' and YEAR(M.FchMovim)=2019
    ) TablaRetiro,
    (
        SELECT sum(M.ImporteMovim) as Trans 
        FROM Movimiento M
        where m.TipoMovim='T' and YEAR(M.FchMovim)=2019
    ) TablaTransferencia
```

Se que la falla esta en el que el AVG Necesitaria un group by, pero sinceramente no encuentro donde iria en este caso

Comment: Tablas:
Sucursal(IdSucursal,DscSucursal,DirSucursal,MailSucursal,TelSucursal)
-
TipoCuenta(IdTipo,DscTipo)

Moneda(IdMoneda,DscMoneda,SimboloMoneda)

Cliente(IdCliente,NombreCliente,TipoCliente,TelCliente,MailCliente)

Cuenta(IdCuenta,IdTipo,IdMoneda,IdSucursal,IdCliente)

Movimiento(IdMovim,FchMovim,TipoMovim,IdCuenta,ImporteMovim) 

Transferencia(IdTransfer,FchTransfer,IdMovim,TipoTransfer,CtaDestino,BancoDestino,StatusTransfer)

Comment: Edita tu pregunta usando el boton [edit]. Aparte, ya que estas, aclara en el tag que base de datos estas usando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el promedio lo puedes obtener de tu subconsulta TablaTransferencia, quitalo de tu consulta principal

ejemplo:

```
 (
        SELECT avg(M.ImporteMovim) as Trans 
        FROM Movimiento M
        where m.TipoMovim='T' and YEAR(M.FchMovim)=2019
    ) TablaTransferencia
```